# Which and how do i use a compiler with eclipse juno (newest one)?

Tags: c++, eclipse

i am learning c++ using eclipse. I have heard that i need a compiler with it. Which one should i use and how do i add it? Also if there is a better ide than eclipse for c++ please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux boxes come with GCC built right in. If not, fire up the package manager and install.

Mac I can't speak on.

For Windows your easiest choices are [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx).

My preference goes to MinGW because of tight integration with Eclipse.

If you go with using Visual Studio, learn using the IDE that comes with it. Once you know C++ and gain some experience, then try using using Eclipse with it as Eclipse doesn't work well out of the box with Visual Studio. Until you know what the error messages that will come your way mean, Visual Studio under Eclipse will just cause you grief.

As for better IDE, that's a matter of preference, but real men use [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) and start fires by spitting on wood really, really fast.

## EDIT

If anyone has experience with the current state of Clang support in Eclipse, please chime in.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say what operating system you're running on. For Windows, you can [download Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx). For Linux, GCC works well, so if g++ at a command prompt isn't found, you should install the build-essential package, like this:
sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential` command fails on a very large number of linux distros.